# Scala traits with generic

Tags: scala

I used to develop on java, but now I stucked with one thing.

I have some kind of flexible value system.

```
trait Value[T] {
  def get:T
}
```

I have implementations of this, for example

```
class StringValue(value : String) extends Value[String] {
  override def get : String = value
}

class NumberValue(value : Int) extends Value[Int] {
  override def get: Int = value
}
```

Then, I'm passing Value to Map, but I don't need parameter, as I don't know which implementation should be used.

```
case class Foo(attributes: Map[Attribute, Value)
```

On this step I get an error, because Value should have parameter.

I understand that it's might be fundamental difference between Java and Scala, so what should I use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use existential types: `Map[Attribute, Value[_]]` to express this, but they aren't trivial to use.

> I understand that it's might be fundamental difference between Java and Scala

It isn't: in Java you *can* write `Map<Attribute, Value>`, but [you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). Instead, you want `Map<Attribute, Value<?>>` which is more limited than Scala, but expresses the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along the lines of

```
case class Foo[K, V](attributes: Map[K, V])
```

You need to have the class have generic typed parameters in order to be able to use generic parameters.